# how to restrict sa  permission on my database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a database installed on my SQL SERVER and I want that no one open it even the super admin. only the person who has the user name password can open it

Comment: The sa account is admin for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following to enable or disable the sa account

```
/* Disable SA Login */
ALTER LOGIN [sa] DISABLE
GO
/* Enable SA Login */
ALTER LOGIN [sa] ENABLE
GO
```

Answer (score -1):

You can not remove/restrict SA login from any database. This is one of the reason you go for seperate instance, so that you can have your own SA password

Comment: not true...  It's very common for attacks to focus on the SA account.  For that reason, you can rename it, or disable it (and in fact, it is recommended that you do.)